# Is the parameterization by arc length unique?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I have the following problem which I don't know if it's true:

Let $\varphi: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi: J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be parameterizations of a curve $\Gamma$ such that $\varphi '(t), \psi '(s)$ are unitary vectors for every $t\in I, s\in J$. Then there exist a smooth map $\alpha: I\rightarrow J$ surjective such that $\alpha '(t)\neq 0$ for every $t\in I$ and $\psi = \varphi \circ \alpha$.

If such map exist, I proved that this map must be $\alpha(t) = t_0 +t$ or $\alpha(t) = t_0 -t$. But, I don't see how this map works...

Any idea?..

Comment: Suggestion: Let $\alpha := \psi^{-1}\circ\varphi$ and see what you can deduce from your hypotheses. (To do so, interpret the codomain of $\psi$ as $\Gamma$, not the whole Cartesian space.)